# Django model - how to avoid orphant related objects?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a modelling question. Suppose I have the following model - a database of movie reviews, where ratings to a given Movie can be given separately by multiple Critics and multiple Persons (ordinary Joe viewers):

```
class Person(models.Model):
#    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False, default=None, unique=True)
    ratings = models.ManyToManyField('Rating',
        related_name="persons"
    )

class Critic(models.Model):
#    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False, default=None, unique=True)
    ratings = models.ManyToManyField('Rating',
        related_name="critics"
    )

class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False, default=None, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"

class Rating(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, models.CASCADE)
    value = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.movie}:{self.value}"
```

when I want to populate the Database, it's all fine, but there is one step where a rating object is created, then added to a user's list of ratings, see below.

```
>>> from imdb.models import Person, Critic, Movie, Rating
>>> m = Movie(title="Movie1")
>>> m.save()
>>> p = Person(name="p1")
>>> p.save()
>>> r = Rating(movie=m,value=5)
>>> r.save()
>>> p.ratings.add(r)
>>> p.ratings.all()
<QuerySet [<Rating: Movie1:5>]>
```

Is this a correct pattern? Is it possible to ensure no orphant ratings? I.e. create a rating and add it to a user more or less atomically?

I tried the following that didn't work:

```
p.ratings.add(Rating(movie=m3,value=2))
#error
p.ratings.add(Rating(movie=m3,value=2).save())
#no error, rating created, but not added
```

Note, that I have a Critic with related ratings too, so not an option to have a user field on Rating class.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since your `Rating` has a `ForeignKey` to `Movie`, and that `ForeignKey` is non-`NULL`able, it always refers to a `Movie`. Normally the database will enforce this.

Comment: It is not clear to me why there is no `ForeignKey` to the `Critic`, with the current modeling, a `Review` can belong to *multiple* `Critic`s?

Comment: Right, but this only attaches a Rating to a movie, but not to a User. A rating to a given Movie can be given separately by multiple Critics and multiple Persons (ordinary Joe viewers). If you have a right model in mind, please post. My model could all be wrong, since don't know to how to ensure consistency :)

Comment: you can use a `ForeignKey` to the `User` as well. It is not clear to me why you have a `ManyToManyField` from `User` to `Rating` (nor exactly what `Critic` is doing here). With a `ManyToManyField`, it looks as if multiple users can write for the *same* review, but that looks quite "odd".

Comment: If users can be critics, you can simply make a model with a `OneToOneField` to user, then you link the ratings to the user, you can thus then see if that user is a crtici, but it thus simplifies the modeling.

Comment: Ok, so uncomment `user` fields on `Person` and `Critic`, then add `user=model.ForeignKey(User)` to `Rating`?

Comment: If I understood the problem correctly, yes.

Comment: Ok, thank! But, in principle, isn't it possible to create a new object on the fly, like I tried with `.add()` ?

Comment: no since we need the primary key of the two objects to link it. You can use `p.ratings.create(movie=m. value=5)`, but behind the curtains, that will make two queries. You can wrap it in transactions to avoid errors, but a many-to-many here simply looks conceptually wrong, since, as said before, it means multiple users/persons/... can be related to the *same* rating.

Comment: So, this means, in my case, once I add `user=model.ForeignKey(User, related_name="ratings")` to Rating, I can just remove `ratings` field in `Person` and `Critic` and use related_name, I guess?